# Run a shell script multiple times at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a `shell` script called `test.sh` and a argument file called `xaa` in a directory. Location of the directory is `/home/$USER/par`

To run this script I am doing

```
cd /home/$USER/par
```

and then

```
./test.sh xaa
```

Until now the script works fine

Now I want to run the same `test.sh` script for different argument files like `xab`, `xac`, `xad` and so on at the same time.

what I want is to invoke `test.sh`

```
./test.sh xaa
./test.sh xab
./test.sh xac
./test.sh xad
```

all at the same time from one terminal only.

How can I achieve my requirement.

Comment: [`xargs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) to the rescue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest of the ways to do this would be to use the `&` notation to put them as background processes.

```
for arg in xaa xab xac xad; do
    ./test.sh "$arg" &
done
```

You could also read up the parallelization techniques provided by `xargs` or GNU `parallel` for more computation intensive tasks.